# Google api image search with python

Tags: python, image

Google api for image search has been depricated, 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0'. Is there any other library or package that could be used to search images from google?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look on [GoogleScraper](https://github.com/NikolaiT/GoogleScraper):

```
from GoogleScraper import scrape_with_config

config = {
    'SCRAPING': {
        'keyword': 'image keyword',
        'search_engines': 'google',
        'search_type': 'image',
        'scrapemethod': 'selenium'
    }
}

scrape_with_config(config)
```